# Redirect to another any episerver page from MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver

How to redirect to any page (eg Home) from any MVC controller in Episerver? eg after login - redirect to the start page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To redirect to any MVC action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Redirect to the configured start page of the site:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    PageData startPage =
        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>().Get<PageData>(ContentReference.StartPage);

    // get URL of the start page
    string startPageUrl = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>()
                .GetVirtualPath(startPage.ContentLink, startPage.LanguageBranch);

    return Redirect(startPageUrl);
}
```

Comment: In EpiServer 11+ you need to access the VirtualPath on the object. 

In the above example the code should be: 
`return Redirect(startPageUrl.VirtualPath);`

I just tested this on EpiServer 11 and not 10.

Answer (score 11):

You can actually still use the RedirectToAction with EPiServer, as long as you also supply the content reference of the page.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("ActionName", new { node = ContentReference.StartPage });
}
```

This has been tested in EPiServer 7.5.440.0.

Comment: I really like this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use RedirectToAction() to redirect to a specific action or Redirect() to a specific URL. In ASP.NET MVC 4 you can use RedirectToLocal() in stead of Redirect(), this is recommended for security reasons when you use a parameter from the querystring.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    // Use this for an action
    return RedirectToAction("Action");
    // Use this for a URL
    return Redirect("/"); // (Website root)
    // Use this for a URL within your domain
    return RedirectToLocal("/"); // (Website root)
}
```

See this following links for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In EpiServer 11 I find it to be cleaner to utilize dependency injection instead of utilizing the ServiceLocator as suggested by Thomas Krantz.

**Example using Dependency Injection:**

```
public class SomeController 
{
   private readonly IContentLoader _contentLoader;
   private readonly UrlResolver _urlResolver;

   public SomeController(IContentLoader contentLoader, UrlResolver urlResolver)
   {
     _contentLoader = contentLoader ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contentLoader));
     _urlResolver = urlResolver ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(urlResolver));
   }

   public ActionResult Index(SomePage currentPage)
   {
     //Retrieving an example startpage type
     var startPageContentLink =_contentLoader.Get<StartPageType>(ContentReference.StartPage);
     //Getting the redirect link -> Type: VirtualPathData
     var redirectLink = urlResolver.GetVirtualPath(startPageContentLink);

     return Redirect(redirectLink.VirtualPath);
   }
}
```

Naturally this lacks some validation, when using the content loader (it might throw an exception if your given StartPageType does not exist).